# Ruby on rails - Helper method - undefined method `log_in' in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing login based on Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition. Stuck in chapter 8.

Defining a new `log_in` helper function in `SessionsHelper` as below. When I try to access the same function in `SessionController`, I am getting the undefined method `log_in`:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

and SessionCOntroller code is

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `ApplicationController` part [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#code-sessions_helper_include) which includes the helper in the controller so its methods can be accessible directly:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Comment: cool, glad to be helpful. Care to set my answer as the correct one then so this gets off the "unanswered" bucket?